# Help with Ubuntu installation - getting the "System program problem detected" error

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

[image]I failed during an attempt to reinstall Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop (which was installed on my Acer Aspire laptop alongside Windows 11). I had problems with the reinstallation, so I decided to delete the Ubuntu partition, add the created free space to the Windows partition, and delete the Ubuntu entry from the boot menu. Now I am able to run Windows. Next, I want to dual boot Ubuntu again. But during the installation, I always get an error message stating "System program problem detected". This always happens at the step where I arrange the new partition for Ubuntu. I attach the picture of my partitions before creating the new partition (which leads to the error).

I thought that my installation USB stick might be corrupted, so I recreated it (using balena Etcher) but the result is still the same.

I have no idea what could be wrong. Please help me to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 11.

This is the input of one of the two files in /var/crash/  :

> {
> "kind": "SERVER_REQUEST_FAIL"
> }

The input of the second file is so long that I have problems to copy it here but it starts like this:

```
> ProblemType: Bug
Architecture: amd64
CrashDB: {'impl': 'launchpad', 'project': 'subiquity'}
CurrentDmesg:
 [    0.000000] microcode: updated early: 0x8a -> 0xac, date = 2023-02-27
 [    0.000000] Linux version 6.5.0-9-generic (buildd@bos03-amd64-043) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41) #9-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Oct  7 01:35:40 UTC 2023 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-9.9-generic 6.5.3)
 [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz layerfs-path=minimal.standard.live.squashfs --- quiet splash
 [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
 [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
 [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
 [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
 [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
 [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
 [    0.000000] x86/split lock detection: #AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_locks and warning on user-space split_locks
 [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003fd98fff] usable
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000003fd99000-0x0000000040698fff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040699000-0x00000000424aefff] usable
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000424af000-0x00000000442fefff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000442ff000-0x0000000044b2efff] ACPI NVS
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044b2f000-0x0000000044bfefff] ACPI data
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044bff000-0x0000000044bfffff] usable
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044c00000-0x0000000048ffffff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000049e00000-0x000000004f7fffff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe010000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff500000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
 [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000002b07fffff] usable
 [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
 [    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.7 by INSYDE Corp.
 [    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0x44bfe000 ACPI 2.0=0x44bfe014 TPMFinalLog=0x44ac5000 SMBIOS=0x429de000 SMBIOS 3.0=0x429dc000 MEMATTR=0x3bede018 ESRT=0x3bf55a98 MOKvar=0x429b5000 INITRD=0x3bed5498 RNG=0x44b77018 TPMEventLog=0x3b483018 
 [    0.000000] random: crng init done
 [    0.000000] efi: Remove mem80: MMIO range=[0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (256MB) from e820 map
 [    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] reserved
 [    0.000000] efi: Not removing mem81: MMIO range=[0xfe010000-0xfe010fff] (4KB) from e820 map
 [    0.000000] efi: Remove mem83: MMIO range=[0xff500000-0xffffffff] (11MB) from e820 map
 [    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0xff500000-0xffffffff] reserved
 [    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot enabled
 [    0.000000] Kernel is locked down from EFI Secure Boot mode; see man kernel_lockdown.7
 [    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.
 [    0.000000] DMI: Acer Aspire A515-56/Iris_TL, BIOS V1.35 07/10/2023
 [    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2400.000 MHz processor
 [    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2419.200 MHz TSC
 [    0.000004] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
 [    0.000006] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
 [    0.000011] last_pfn = 0x2b0800 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
 [    0.000014] MTRR map: 5 entries (3 fixed + 2 variable; max 23), built from 10 variable MTRRs
 [    0.000015] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
 [    0.000447] last_pfn = 0x44c00 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
 [    0.007905] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x000000003bf55a98 to 0x000000003bf55ad0.
 [    0.007909] e820: update [mem 0x3bf55000-0x3bf55fff] usable ==> reserved
 [    0.007923] Using GB pages for direct mapping
 [    0.008205] secureboot: Secure boot enabled
 [    0.008205] RAMDISK: [mem 0x2ecd0000-0x3540afff]
 [    0.008705] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
 [    0.008708] ACPI: RSDP 0x0000000044BFE014 000024 (v02 ACRSYS)
 [    0.008711] ACPI: XSDT 0x0000000044BDB188 000124 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000002      01000013)
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time trying to resolve the issue, I managed to solve it by creating another installation USB stick using the LEGACY Ubuntu installer. It seems that there is something wrong with the new installer. The legacy installer worked like a charm.